# How can I get NgModel value from Angular2 Pipe

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have created a common search pipe for table, I have also added the column values to the select box, now I need to get the selected value from the select box and access it in my pipes

Below are the Code for your Reference

**Pipe**

```
export class searchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(values: any[], filter: string, selectedvalue:any): any {
    console.log(selectedvalue);
    if (!values || !values.length) return [];
    if (!filter) return values;
    filter = filter.toUpperCase();
    if (filter && Array.isArray(values)) {
      const keys = Object.keys(values[0]);
      return values.filter(v => v && keys.some(k => v[k].toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) >= 0));
    }
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<select *ngIf="showColFilter" [(ngModel)]="selecedValues">
  <option *ngFor="let colValues of tabData | columnPipe">{{colValues}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You can pass multiple params separating values with semi-colons - 
`columnPipe:filter:selectedValue`. Here is link to the docs:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#custom-pipes

Comment: I cannot give columnPipe:filter:selectedValue like this in my template which is pointing to search filter

Comment: Probably, I'm missing something, but the selected value is passed as expected: https://plnkr.co/edit/B3Tr1I2saLOxIXGjA8xU?p=preview (please ignore the erratic selection, as the selected item is removed from the options).
Could you update your question and post a plunker repo?

Comment: @GeorgeK here is the plunkr repo https://plnkr.co/edit/iR64EKawUzIfcYc3T4db?p=preview

Comment: Several things:
1. (ngModel) cannot be used without FormsModule!
2. Arguments passed to the pipe are not mapped by name! You will need to always pass the filter and selected value
Here is the updated plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/8rul0gyjySbulwj9kUyl?p=preview

Comment: @GeorgeK thanks, but one small doubt am having when I enter an input n the textbox the selected value in the pipe become undefined do u know why

Answer (score -3):

`<select [(ngModel)]="colvalues">`
`<div *ngFor="let colValues of tabData | columnPipe">`
`<option value="colValues">`
`</option>`
`</div>`
`</select>`

Use this code to get value in ngModel

Comment: do u get what the question is ?. I need to access the ngModel values inside another pipe

Comment: dont give useless answer. try to analyse the question and then post accordingly